# What do I call the grammar at "following"?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, time

> The purpose of the workshop is to improve the company following discussion with the company's employees.

I'm not sure about the word *following*. What is its grammar function in the sentence?

Comment: *Following* can be used as a preposition. See http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read it:

> The purpose of the workshop is to improve the company, following **discussions** with the company's employees.

Adding a comma after *company*. When writen this way, discussions with the employees provided feedback for the workshop.

*following* is a preposition in this usage.

Answer (score 0):

This sentence is a little confusing. I think it might be reworded to:

> After the employees discuss it, the workshop should improve the company.

Although I am not sure if this is the meaning you are trying to impart. *Following* is a synonym to *after*.

EDIT: Some comments have suggested another possible meaning.

> The purpose of the workshop is to improve the company according to the suggestions of the employees.

In this case, *following* is a synonym to *according to*.

Comment: But *following* could also be *along the lines of* as in "The purpose of the workshop is to improve the company as was discussed with the employees."

Comment: Above sentence, i have got from England person in English and usage. But i have some confused that.

Comment: Do you remember if the speaker of the sentence paused for a second after the word *company*? That might imply the meaning suggested by user3169.